# ActiveModelSerializer - serialize array object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers

I have problems with ActiveModelSerializer.

Model test.rb:

```
class Test < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attr_accessor :id, :userName, :lista, :test2

  def initialize params = {}
    @lista = Array.new
    @test2 = Array.new
    params.each { |key, value| send "#{key}=", value }
  end
end
```

Model test2.rb:

```
class Test2 < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attr_accessor :id, :userName

  def initialize params = {}
    params.each { |key, value| send "#{key}=", value }
  end
end
```

test_serializer.rb:

```
class TestSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :userName, :lista
  attributes :test2

  public

  def test2
    Test2Serializer.new(object.test2).as_json
  end
end
```

test2_serializer.rb:

```
class Test2Serializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :userName
end
```

I get an error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined methodread_attribute_for_serialization’ for #Array:0x00007f1bb52da460):
```

After debuggin the code I found out that the Exception is from this line:

```
object.read_attribute_for_serialization(attr)
```

In variable object is an array. I think it should be object. So I tried to change

```
Test2Serializer.new(object.test2).as_json
```

oto

```
json: object.test2, each_serializer: Test2Serializer
```

or:

```
object.test2, each_serializer: Test2Serializer
```

That didn't work. Can anyone help me?